# I can't add jQuery to WebStorm, why?

Tags: jquery, webstorm

I want to add jQuery to WebStorm (IDE by JetBrains), but it doesn't have any option to add it automatically. I also tried downloading jQuery from the website and installing it through the "Install Plugin from Disk" section, but it doesn't show up.

[image: Nothing here]

[image: Or here]

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since jQuery is a JavaScript library, it looks like it's installed via the JavaScript Support plugin: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/javascript-libraries.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

jQuery is just a library, so you don't need a full plug-in for it;  all you need to do is ...

1. Go to Settings (or Preferences on a Mac)
2. Go to Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Code Libraries
3. Click "Download"
4. Find jQuery and select it
5. Click "Download and Install"

After that jQuery variables (most notably `$`) should no longer have squiggly lines under them, and you should be able to auto-complete jQuery functions.  And that same basic pattern should work for pretty much any other Javascript library that you want Webstorm to support (the list of downloadable libraries is fairly comprehensive).

Comment: On a Mac you can find it by going to "Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries" and there is a Download button in the right side of the Preferences window.