# VueJS doesn't load Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am planning to use bootstrap so I first imported jquery.min file by using `require()` in `main.js` However, bootstrap throws an error like Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery even I imported the jquery file before bootstrap.

main.js:

```
import vueResource from 'vue-resource';
import VueHead from 'vue-head';
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';

require('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
require('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
require('../node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css');
require('./assets/css/app.css');

require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min');
require('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min');
.....
```

I installed bootstrap(version 3.3.7) and jquery(version 3.2.1) from `npm`.

What is the correct way to import jquery so bootstrap won't throw the not found jquery error?

Comment: I don't think `jquery.min` or `bootstrap.min` will work. `.min` is just a version of the file that has all unnecessary characters removed in order to make the file size smaller. You still need to indicate what type of file this is. Looks like you just need to add `.js` after both `jquery.min` and `bootstrap.min`.

Comment: adding `.js` after both of them didn't change anything. I am using WebStorm application to build the project. It actually wrote that path without `.js`

Comment: Ah, interesting. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with WebStorm. I did, however, come across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401482/i-cant-add-jquery-to-webstorm-why) that may help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose jQuery globally so that bootstrap can initialise using jQuery object.

Try this:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ =require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min')
```