# Sending the input of a textarea by clicking on submit button using jQuery/AJAX to a Flask backend

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, dom, submit-button

I am trying to write the jQuery code for a submit button following a [tutorial](https://codehandbook.org/python-flask-jquery-ajax-post/). I intend to send the data from this submit button (the content of a textarea in bootstrap) to the backend which is written in Flask. However, Webstorm shows there are problems in the code. How should I fix them?

main.js:

```
/* submit button */

$(function () {
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url:'/submitData',
                            data: $('form').serialize(),
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function (error){
                            console.log(error)
                        }
                    });
    });

});
```

part of HTML

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea4" rows="3"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-purple purple-border" value="Submit">
```

As you see below lines 3, 4, 5, and 8 have a problem.
[image]

For example, line 3:

[image]

Comment: Looks like WebStorm can't find the jQuery reference.  Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401564/3120130) answer on how to reference jQuery in WebStorm

Comment: Your `<texarea>` needs a `name`. Also, you have no `<button>` elements. I recommend binding to the form's _submit_ event instead of button click, ie `$('form').on('submit', ...`

Comment: downloading the jQuery from Preference fixed those line problems but using on('submit') gives me error on line 4 here https://pastebin.com/3rTSpQZM @Phil

Comment: You want `$('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({ ... }) })`. See https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Duplicate of [I can't add jQuery to WebStorm, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401482/i-cant-add-jquery-to-webstorm-why)

Comment: yes combination of your last two response works (added my finalized code here) https://pastebin.com/8N073EKP thanks

Comment: @Phil I need to add the jQuery in <head></head> before bootstrap js how do I know which version is installed by Webstorm now? jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.